# Want to delete array

Tags: php

Can anyone help me to improve this code? I want to delete array if it already exists. Thanks

```
if(count($cart['Item']) > 0) {
    unset($cart['Item']);

    $items['Item'] = array();
    $cart = array_merge($cart, $items);
}
```

Comment: Have a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Could you explain what exactly do you want to do here?

Comment: Do you want to delete the array if it exists or empty it if it has content?

Comment: @iAndr0idOs, want to delete array if exist `$cart['Item']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you want the `$cart['Item']` variable to be an empty array after this step, no matter what it was before. So:

```
$cart['Item'] = array();
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($cart['Item'])) {
    unset($cart['Item']);
}
```

- `!empty` requires the array item to be both existent and not falsy (e.g. empty)
- `unset` will delete the given key from `$cart`

However, if you want to replace it with a new, empty array:

```
$cart['Item'] = array();
```

No need to do anything else. PHP has a Garbage Collector.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to check if it exists. using isset() is faster in your case. Then you can just override it without any unsetting.

```
if( isset($cart['Item']))
{   
    $cart['Item'] = array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
if(isset($cart['Item']) && !empty($cart['Item'])) {
    unset($cart['Item']);

}else{
    $items['Item'] = array();
    $cart = array_merge($cart, $items);
 }
```

Thanks.